# How to get designated apps to open on designated desktops

Tags: macos

I would like to get TextMate and Safari to open in the same desktop, but have looked in System Preferences and can't see where to do this?

Leopard and Snow Leopard had this in System Preferences, but I can't find it in Lion.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you have **at least two** spaces in Mission Control, you can access the necessary options via right-click on the app icon in the dock:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In 13.1 it is not possible. Options menu was changed.